# SQLITE_ERROR SQL error or missing database (near "(": syntax error)

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

> [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "(": syntax error)

```java
try {
    String sql = "SELECT MAX (right(id_kasir,3)) AS no FROM tbl_kasir";
    st = connection.createStatement();
    rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
    while (rs.next()) {
        if (rs.first() == false) {
            txtidkasir.setText("KS001");
        } else {
            rs.last();
            int auto_id = rs.getInt(1) + 1;
            String no = String.valueOf(auto_id);
            int noLong = no.length();
            for (int a = 0; a < 3 - noLong; a++) {
                no = "0" + no;
            }
            txtidkasir.setText("KS" + no);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error" + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: try remove the space between max and (     eg:   max(...)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Seems like there is a limit to the depth of SQL in Sqlite.
My solution was to create a view with the SQL, than do avg, max and min on that views.

Answer (score -1):

You have missing ; at the end. And maybe need to specify the database.

> SELECT MAX(right(id_kasir,3)) AS no FROM tbl_kasir;

try:

> SELECT MAX(right(id_kasir,3)) AS no FROM {DBName}.tbl_kasir;

Comment: The semicolon is optional. And your "fixed" query has a syntax error.